# jQuery: Controller function not being executed correctly with ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I am programming a web application in C# MVC which dynamically loads information from a server in order to improve the speed.

Currently I have some errors and I am unable to diagnose why these are causing issues so I'll try my best to explain what's happening:

This div is created many times and grabs the ID for each project.

```
<div>
     <a href='@item.LinkToJiraByStatus("Open")' target="_blank">Open</a>:
     @{string JiraKey = item.JiraProjectKey;}
     <span id="JiraOpen" onload="GetOpenJira"></span>
</div>
```

Then in the span, the script GetOpenJira is initiated:

```
 <script id="GetOpenJira">
    var url = "/HicVault/Projects/GetNumJiraOpenByKey";
    var key = $('#JiraKey').val();
    $.get(url, { input: key }, function (data) { $("#JiraOpen").html(data) });
</script>
```

This script SHOULD asynconously ask the controller to complete the function GetNumJiraOpenByKey with the JiraKey being used as a parameter. The function in the controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetNumJiraOpenByKey(string JiraProjectKey)
    {
        var sJql = "project = \"" + JiraProjectKey + "\" and status = \"Open\""; 
        var resultFieldNames = new List<string> { "resolution" };
        Issues issues = new JiraClient(new JiraAccount()).GetIssuesByJql(sJql, 0, 1000, resultFieldNames);
        return PartialView(issues.total);
    }
```

Essentially this function returns an int once it has counted all of the issues for that particular project. I would like this to be done with AJAX using jQuery to load these values after the page has been loaded to vastly increase speed. (Currently without AJAX, pages take >30 sec to load).

Thanks if anyone can help.

EDIT: I suppose I should ask a question, currently with this code the page loads and after around 5 seconds, a server 500 error appears in the console stating there is an Internal Server Error. I know this is a general error, going in deeper points to the line:

```
"$.get(url, { input: key }, function (data) { $("#JiraOpen").html(data) ".
```

I am guessing either the logic of my work isn't possible in Razor MVC + JS, or I am getting the fundamentals of jQuery ajax get wrong?

Comment: "Currently I have some errors" which errors?

Comment: Edit made: Its just a generic 500 internal server error. I also cannot test the controller method on its own with a Url for some reason.

Comment: If you execute the page locally the 500 will contain the exception message, if you can't execute it locally you can modify your web.config to show exceptions even for remote calls: http://forums.asp.net/t/1209749.aspx?how+to+allow+web+application+to+display+error+message+on+remote+IIS+Server+

Comment: `send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8720`,
`jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8150`,
`jQuery.(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8296`,
`(anonymous function) @ (index):310`,

These are the errors, with it originating from : `"$.get(url, { input: key }, function (data) { $("#JiraOpen").html(data) ". `

Comment: @user3891848 Since you get a 500 error you look server-side 
Do you pass correctly the string in your function?
`string JiraProjectKey = Request.QueryString["input"];` to use with 
`GetNumJiraOpenByKey(string JiraProjectKey)`, i am not familiar with c# but you don't have syntax error in $.get. Could you use something like `GetNumJiraOpenByKey(Request.QueryString["input"])` in c# ?

Comment: @PeterDarmis Hi! I have tried this just and it still produces the exact same error. I have also tried gypsyCoder's response to no avail. :/

Comment: You have to check line by line your server-side method GetNumJiraOpenByKey. Print JiraProjectKey string right after the method starts to check it's value that it is the appropriate one.

Comment: Shall try this out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: So it seems the function in the controller wasn't liking the string format. Thankfully using console.log(key) aided greatly in diagnosing why. It is fixed now, however only Ajaxifies it all once, and resets when the div is collapsed. Nonetheless, thanks for the help, it's pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your script as following...

```
 <script id="GetOpenJira">
    var url = "/HicVault/Projects/GetNumJiraOpenByKey";
    var key = $('#JiraKey').val();
    $.get(url, { JiraProjectKey: key }, function (data) { $("#JiraOpen").html(data) });
 </script>
```

Comment: Tried this. Unfortunately it is still resulting in the same issue, with the $.get being pointed to in the stack trace. Do you think it the logic of my code should work? I am still unsure if what I am trying to do is possible :)

Comment: Your error is occurring at the server side. You should review your server-side codebase.